# Publishing a Google Apps Script "app" that needs a spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script

I created a script to help me manipulate the *change time* of files and folders in Google Drive and I published it on [github](https://github.com/mciobanu/GDriveTimeManager). I wonder if it makes sense to even talk about publishing it to *Google Workspace Marketplace*, and, if it does, how to actually go about it, as I wasn't able to find something that fits my situation.

The installation process is described [at github](https://github.com/mciobanu/GDriveTimeManager#installation), but the gist of it is that you create a spreadsheet in your drive, open it, click on *Extensions* menu and then on *App Script*, copy the actual script, save, close the spreadsheet and reopen it. Then it will add some menu entries and sheets, and those menu entries will implement said manipulations.

What makes this app different from others I looked at is this idea that you need your own spreadsheet, and then you attach the script to it. (Also, I wasn't able to find something like this in *Google Workspace Marketplace*'s publishing documentation.)

What I tried:

1. I read through Google's documentation but I couldn't find a match.
2. I looked at what several apps do, but I couldn't find any similar one.
3. I asked Bard and ChatGPT. Both gave precise instructions which didn't match reality.

So:

1. Can this thing be published to *Google Workspace Marketplace*? If so, how?
2. Would simply making public an empty spreadsheet with the script attached work? (It should be read-only and the users would need to create copies to their own drive.)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the normal publishing process described in the  [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/how-tos/publish-add-on-overview). Things to note:

- Script should be standalone, when  writing. It'll be bound to sheet automatically, when testing or when a user installs it.
- You need to account for [differences in authorization](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/concepts/editor-auth-lifecycle) between published and unpublished addons(which is what you essentially have now).

Comment: Thank you, it looks like a lot of work for something that probably few, if any, will ever want, especially for authorization (logo, home page, privacy policy, new emails, etc).

I guess I'll wait to see if anybody has anything to say about the github version, and perhaps reconsider in the future.

Comment: @ciobi There are ready made templates. You can directly link to your github for privacy policy, homepages, etc. Another option would be to publish a library, but it cannot  trigger `onOpen` directly. End user needs to create triggers and write some code.

Comment: I'm afraid I still don't get it. Let's say I'm past the publishing part and now somebody finds it in Workspace Marketplace and installs it. Now what? Will all the spreadsheets get the extra menus and my other changes? This is not OK. The script should run in a single spreadsheet (or several, if the user wants to), but not in all of them. For one thing, it changes the content. I guess I could wait until the user initiates a change, but I still don't want to have the new menus visible in all spreadsheets (and it doesn't seem possible to allow only individual installations).

Comment: @ciobi Everything you said is possible-Carefully read everything in the second link in my answer. The add-on runs in ``Auth.NONE`` mode, where the option to enable the add-on and present the full menu would be provided under Addons submenu(see last code sample in documentation). If you still have doubts after reading the second link in my answer, ask and I'll be happy to clarify.